# Empirical estimation of Brenier map from data

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, optimal-transportation

Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be a "nice" (say, continuous) function define $A = A_f := \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid f(x) \ge 0\}$ and $B =B_f:= \{x \in \mathbb R^d \mid f(x) \le 0\}$, and suppose their common boundary $Z_f := \{f = 0\}$ has $d$-dimensional volume equal to $0$ (which is the case, if for example, $Z_f$ has positive codimension).

Let $P$ be a "nice" distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ which has density density w.r.t Lebesgue (e.g, a mixture of 2 gaussians), and define a distribution $1_A$ (resp. $1_B$) by  $1_A(U) := P(U|A) = \dfrac{P(U \cap A)}{P(A)}$, for any measurable $U \subseteq \mathbb R^d$.

> **Question.** What is an efficient way to empirically compute the optimal transport plan $T$ (w.r.t cost $c(x,y) = -x^\top y$) from $1_A$ to $(1_A+1_B)/2$ by simply evaluating $f$ (on perhaps randomly selected) points in $\mathbb R^d$ ?

- The efficacy of such an algorithm will be the number of times $n$ the function $f$ is evaluated.
- The algorithm should be consistence in that if $\hat{T}$ is the output of the algorithm, then in the limit $n \to \infty$, we should have $\hat{T} \to T$ in some sense.

### Observations

- Since $1_A$ has density w.r.t Lebesgue (really ?), a result of Brenier ensures that $T$ maybe chosen in the form $T = \nabla \phi$, for some convex $C^1$ function $\phi:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$. Thus, one could instead try to estimate $\phi$, which ought to be presumably much easier.

Comment: Did you have a look at Santambrogio's book: Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians ?  In particular, the Section 6 contains a nice overview of numerical methods.

Comment: I have it, but I'm on holidays (and so really shouldn't be pondering on these things) without my library. I'll try to grab a pdf copy online. Thanks for the input!